# Can I jump to view written objective C from Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have legacy iPad app in objective c. I would like give chance to Appcelerator. But I would not like to rewrite whole app. I would prefer to start with replacing only some views.

Is it possible? If yes could you give me some advice how to start with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this would be very successful. I would say give Appcelerator a shot on your next application.  You can call into objective c / native code FROM appcelerator but it's not totally straight forward.  But trying to mash Appcelerator into an existing iPad application doesn't seem right in my mind.

Also Appcelerator does compile down to a project you can open into Xcode, so maybe you could try to merge some of the code at that level where it is all native.  But, doesn't seem wise.